# Cross columns date counting

Tags: tableau-api

I have a dataset below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzTup.png)

Date 1 – Initial day

Date 2 – Event_A date

Date 3 – Event B date , etcs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOSiG.png)

Somehow I would like to drag Month(Date1) in Column and count Date6 (Aug/Sep) ,

because All data in Data1 is in March, so that in Mar columns ,the count value is 5.

But what I would like to have is that

keeping Date1 in column as it is
Instead of shows 5 in Mar, I want it to 4 in Aug and 1 in Sep.

In order word, the month it shows the numbers is depend of the Month(DataX), not date1.

enter image description here

The application of this is that I would like to count Data2-6 in one table by dragging date1 in columns.

Hope someone can help

pls find the sample file here

https://filehost.net/57de82bb22be72e5
Thanks

Alex

Comment: So in every date column excluding date1 you need to have the count of months independently.. is that you are looking for?

Comment: @Siva thx for your reply first, yes I want to count them individually but all in one table. Let say a common +year +quarter+month +day that show the value for all date2-6

Comment: `year +quarter+month +day` this combination will always give 1. can you add image of your final output

Comment: I have it here pls find the link https://community.tableau.com/message/742205#742205

Comment: https://community.tableau.com/message/742205#742205  Hi pls find the link

Comment: if possible attach workbook

Comment: Sry for that I thought it was attached. I ll upload it again in 15 mins. Thx for helping

Comment: Hi Siva, i have attached the file here, pls find it https://filehost.net/57de82bb22be72e5. thx

Comment: ok sure give me some time

Comment: file got corrupted... you can attach workbook in tableau community discussion.. attach there do attach in these third party file sharing sites

Comment: Hi Siva, sry for that, i have uploaded the file in tableau site . thx for your help

Comment: Hi Suva. I have uploaded the file in tab com .pls find it there and thx for your help indeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the required design as per your requirement.

Changed and added the workbook in below link

https://community.tableau.com/message/742532#742532

Look for **sheet5**

[image]